# How to render html tag returned from third party webpack bundle inside NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a third party webpack bundle that injects html inside `<app><app/>`

This is the React implementation

```js
import "./bundle.js";
function Appp() {
  return <app />;
}
```

How do I achieve this on NextJS using Client Side rendering.
These are the things I have tried

1. Dynamic Imports

```js
//component
import  './editors/scripts/paperbits'
const Editor =()=>{
    return(
        <app/>
    )
    }
export default Editor

//index.js
const Editor = dynamic(() =>
  import('../editor'),
  { ssr: false }
  
)
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div><Editor/></div>
 )
}
```

In this the script is loading but its not injecting the html

The only thing that works was adding the script and  tag to `_document.js`

Comment: Probably you want to use `webpack` to copy the bundle to the right location and then import it in your `index.html` file. Depends on the usage of the third party webpack bundle.

Comment: @SilvanBregy How do I configure nextjs webpack to enable this

Comment: Do it using `copyWebpackPlugin` => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65622207/adding-copyplugin-to-next-config-js